# CSOM - Incorrect Usage of Exception Handling Scope

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I am trying to use `ExceptionHandlingScope` in a basic Managed client side crud I am getting the error -

> Incorrect Usage of Exception Handling Scopes

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var username = "admin";
            SecureString sPwd = new SecureString();

            foreach (var c in "password")
                sPwd.AppendChar(c);

            SharePointOnlineCredentials cred = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, sPwd);


            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("sharepoint site");

            ctx.Credentials = cred;
            ExceptionHandlingScope eScope = new ExceptionHandlingScope(ctx);
            using (eScope.StartScope())
            {
                using (eScope.StartTry())
                {
                    var listCol = ctx.Web.Lists;
                    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                    query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq>" +
                                        "<FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>3</Value>"
                                        + "</Eq></Where></Query></View>";
                    var list = listCol.GetByTitle("Employehe");
                    var itemCol = list.GetItems(query);
                    ctx.Load(list);
                    ctx.Load(itemCol);
                }
                using (eScope.StartCatch())
                {
                    var msg = eScope.ErrorMessage;
                }
                using (eScope.StartFinally())
                {
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this: http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2010/08/sharepoint-2010-exception-handling.html, there only seem to be try, catch and finally in the scope. Try putting the executeQuery outside the StartScope.